# as3 error says "Stream Error", but when loaded manually it's there

Tags: actionscript-3

I've looked in several other questions, but it just doesn't seem to explain my error.

The error i'm getting is "Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: http://plustg.com/v2/_inc/_swf/getSavedSelfy.php
    at snapshot_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()[snapshot_fla.MainTimeline::frame1:20]"

When going to that URL, it does load. But somehow flash throws a stream error.

For reference, this is all there is on line 20: var selfyXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
And this is the rest of the code:

```
var selfyXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var selfyXMLRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest('http://plustg.com/v2/_inc/_swf/getSavedSelfy.php');

selfyXMLLoader.load(selfyXMLRequest);
selfyXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadSelfy);
```

Strange thing here is that when changing it to any other url on ANOTHER website, it will work.

Help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think some authentication is needed to get the content of this page. I tried to access it and I was prompted with a login/password box and the message: “You need to be a beta tester to view this page.”

Maybe you've already authenticaded in your browser, that would justify the fact that you can access, but not the Flash.

Comment: That's actually an extremely good point. How do i authenticate to it through flash?

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, never heard of that before. Do you know if you can pass the login and password by querystring? Example: ... new URLRequest(...getSavedSelfy.php?login=asd&pass=qwe');

Comment: I know for a fact it isn't possible by doing that. I'm gonna guess that i just have to put said file out of the barrier for now.

Comment: Yeah, if you could use a php page with you own customized auth, and use GET or POST to validate.